# How to create a VeraCrypt rescue disk from "VeraCrypt Rescue Disk.zip"?

Tags: disk-encryption, boot, veracrypt

So I got a "VeraCrypt Rescue Disk.zip" file with an "EFI" folder in it and would like to create a rescue *disk* from it. Meaning I'd like to create a bootable *CD or DVD*, not an USB stick.

Is this possible? Or do I have to create a bootable USB stick (in this case I guess I have to follow [this guide](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/discussions/644091#post1457184), right?)? And if it's possible should I just write the content of the zip file to the disk or how is it supposed to be done?

I cannot do
*System->Create rescue disk* in VeraCrypt as I currently can't boot the respective drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just extracted that .zip file to an USB stick right now (the "EFI" folder) and it worked. After setting my boot mode to UEFI only in bios I could boot from it without following that linked guide and hence without deleting other data on that USB stick.